# Probability That 2 Elements Do Not Belong to a Subset With Size $\le K$

Tags: probability, combinatorics

If we choose a subset $C \subset S$ such that $|S| = N$ and $|C| \le K \le N$, uniformly randomly from all such possible sets, what is the probability that two fixed elements $u,v \in S$ are both not present in $C$?

Is it $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{K}\binom{N-2}{i}}{\sum_{i=1}^{k}\binom{N}{i}}$?

**Edit**: No answers?

Comment: maybe you meant $|S|=N$?

Comment: Yes. Corrected.

Comment: What about the empty set?  The empty set is also a subset.  Should you not sum from $i=0$ instead?  Also on your numerator you have $\sum_{\color{red}{1}=1}^K$, surely you mean to have an indexing variable there.

Comment: No I am only interested in subsets of non zero size. Yes, it was meant to be an index variable I have corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of choosing $C \subset S$ with $0<|C| \le K$, we choose $C^c$ with $N>|C^c| \ge N-K$.
This can be done in $$\sum_{i=N-K}^{N-1} \binom{N}{i} = \sum_{i= N-K}^{N-1} \binom{N}{N-i} = \sum_{i=1}^K \binom{N}{i}$$ different ways.
Then if we have $u,v$ fixed, en we want $u,v \not\in C$, we need $u,v \in C^c$. Thus we need to choose $C^c \backslash \{u,v \}$ from $S \backslash \{ u,v \}$, where the first set needs to have between $N-K-2$ and $N-3$ elements, and the latter set consists of $N-2$ elements.
This can be done in
$$\sum_{i=N-K-2}^{N-3} \binom{N-2}{i} = \sum_{i= N-K-2}^{N-3} \binom{N-2}{N-2-i} = \sum_{i=1}^K \binom{N-2}{i}$$ different ways.

So the probability of choosing $C \subset S$ with $0<|C| \le K$ elements such that $u,v \not\in C$ is indeed, given $N \ge 3$,
$$\frac{ \sum_{i=1}^K \binom{N-2}{i}}{\sum_{i=1}^K \binom{N}{i}}.$$